# In my laravel 8 project auth folder not exist in Controllers folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my laravel project, auth folder is not available in the controller folder ,
because I want to make multi auth but for that, I need LoginController and RegistrationController which is laravel provide by default in

```
Controller---> Auth ---->
```

And then that two files
but in my project there are not files

I have generated laravel auth also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install one of the laravel auth packages like [laravel-breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze)

Answer (score 0):

First of select your laravel version from top right then follow steps to install JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding from here `https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend`